# How to get started with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-community

Every One, recently I started with Magento 1.9 and now also want to start with Magento 2 (for reason).

I need direction to get the start and learn it as soon as possible
and I found very difficult to find a solution when an error occurs.

I know oops basic and for one year, **I was working on CI and PHP core(Procedural).**

Please Help and Thank you!

Comment: take a look at this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store